# MySQLWorkbench quits unexpectedly on MacOS Sonoma 14.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

MacOS, Sonoma 14.0. The moment I try to click on a Model, the app quits. I tried to re-install it but it didn't help.

```
    -------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               MySQLWorkbench [62325]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.34.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2023-10-20 14:08:00.7133 +0300
OS Version:            macOS 14.0 (23A344)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     8.0 (21P365)
Anonymous UUID:        E400A76F-BF85-D586-9F6D-6AC1087798C5

Sleep/Wake UUID:       73D67BBC-193C-442D-A242-5A3BB76EF7A8

Time Awake Since Boot: 240000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       3349 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000e0
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x00000000000000e0

Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process:   exc handler [62325]

VM Region Info: 0xe0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 140737488199456
      REGION TYPE                    START - END         [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      shared memory            7ffffffda000-7ffffffdb000 [    4K] r-x/r-x SM=SHM
```

I tried to re-install MySQL and MySQLWorkbench, but it didn't work. Same with previous versions of the app.

Comment: This seems like a MySQL Tech Support question, not a programming question.